# Is it possible to drop a specific column in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this dataset

```
[[0.96570218 0.97916859 0.         0.98769127]
 [0.96570218 0.97916859 0.         0.98769127]
 [1.         1.         0.         1.        ]
 [1.         1.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.86415196 0.86027468 0.         0.85840598]
 [0.86415196 0.86027468 0.         0.85840598]
 [0.82511791 0.80803283 0.         0.79809695]
 [0.82511791 0.80803283 0.         0.79809695]
 [0.91828023 0.87749393 0.         0.8524262 ]
 [0.91828023 0.87749393 0.         0.8524262 ]
 [0.76760661 0.68182237 0.         0.62934141]
 [0.76760661 0.68182237 0.         0.62934141]
 [0.69375734 0.63615159 0.         0.60151271]
```

I want to drop the second column in the array. I tried this command but it removes the entire dataset not the specific one I want removed:

```
np.delete(dataset, np.s_[:,1], axis=1)
```

Is there a way to do this easily?

(not sure if it matters/helps but for context, I'm taking a dataset and trying to split the dataset and the feature I want before sending it to Keras for training. So I copied the variable(in this case the second column to another variable and now I want to drop it from this array).

Comment: should just be `np.delete(dataset, 1, 1)` ?

Comment: @JonClements When I try np.delete(dataset, locationOfVaraibleToPredict, locationOfVaraibleToPredict)
it shows up as empty like above.

Comment: Right and what is `locationOfVariableToPredict` ?

Comment: @JonClements I'm sorry, that is the variable that contains the location of what I want to delete in this case 1

Comment: It's definitely just an integer with a value of `1` ?

Comment: yes and when i checked the type it's <class 'int'>

Comment: Umm... what's `dataset.shape` show?

Comment: It shows (191, 4). For fun I checked the type and it's type is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Umm.... can you just try: `a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)` then see what `np.delete(a, 1, 1)` returns?

Comment: I'm a  bit new to this, where do I load my data? Dataset into this?

Comment: Err you don't... what I'd like to see is if you just create a brand new array and then do the delete on that if it has the expected results or not...

Comment: So strange, it worked with your command, I did:
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
print(a)
a = np.delete(a, 1, 1)
print(a)

I got:
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
[[ 0  2  3]
 [ 4  6  7]
 [ 8 10 11]]

Comment: sorry looks crappy but at first there was 4 columns and after I ran your second command the second column was deleted.

Comment: Okay... but `np.delete(dataset, 1, 1)` definitely behaves differently?

Comment: It doesn't delete when I do a = np.delete(dataset, 1, 1) and print it  I just get 
<built-in method copy of numpy.ndarray object at 0x1439882b0>

Comment: err - have you done something to `np` or attributes in the module? Seems like you've overwritten something somewhere... cos you definitely shouldn't be getting it's a builtin method blah blah blah as a result

Comment: yes it's so weird..not sure what happened :-(

Comment: Nearly 3am here so I'm calling it a night... good luck!

Comment: Good night and thanks for your help!

Comment: Just seen your comment on the other answer "When I try that, I get this error - TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" - you've definitely shadowed a name somewhere in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])

# using indices
cols = [0,2,3]
arr2 = arr[:,cols]

# using boolean condition
cond = np.arange(arr.shape[-1])!=1  # [True,False,True,True]
arr2 = arr[:,cond]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
col = 2                                          # column idx you want to remove
arr = np.hstack((arr[:,0:col], arr[:,col+1:]))   # ignoring data in 'col'
```

Comment: When I try that, I get this error - TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable